# Save the value of an ID, Class or Name into a variable. Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to save the Email from [10minutemail.net](http://10minutemail.net) into a variable with Python. My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'''C:\WebDriver\chromedriver.exe''') #set driver
email = "" #get from 10minutemail.net

driver.get("https://10minutemail.net")
sleep(2)
#get the email and save it into 'email'
email = driver.find_element_by_id('fe_text')
```

I also tried this:

```
email = driver.find_element_by_id('fe_text').value()
```

But that also didn't work. So how can I save the Email into a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. If you look at the HTML element on the webpage, it looks something like:

```html
<input type="text" id="fe_text" class="mailtext" value="xkb21056@zzrgg.com">
```

Notice that the email is actually a HTML attribute. I don't think there's a `.value()` (I got an error when I did that) but I know you can retrieve the attribute using `get_attribute()`:

```py
email = driver.find_element_by_id('fe_text').get_attribute("value")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fe_text").get_attribute("value")
```